# How to disable and enable specific editText inside a listView in android?

Tags: android, listview, textchanged

I have an editText inside a listview. I used the addTextChangedListener, after the textChange I have a condition when it is true I want to disable all the EditText in listView except the 
one where I use the TextChangeListener

I have this in myCustomAdapter so far :

```
     myHolder.txt_Qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {


            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(isError == true){
                    Log.i("afterchange errorPos", String.valueOf(errorPos));
                    S_4th_SelectItem.lst_listOrder.getChildAt(errorPos).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 153, 204));
                    S_4th_SelectItem.btn_Update.setEnabled(false);

                    myHolder.txt_Qty.setEnabled(false);

                    ((Activity) context).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                }else {
                    S_4th_SelectItem.btn_Update.setEnabled(true);

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you can achieve this by declaring one global boolean variable that indicate myHolder.txt_Qty set enable or disabled and also have to notify adapter using notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable all the `EditText`s by default then add the following before **addTextChangedListener**

```
myHolder.txt_Qty.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I want to disable all the editText that I didn't click so when I click an editText in the first index of child of Listview it means the clicked editText will not be disable.

Comment: If an edittext is already disabled then clicking on it won't even work - because you've asked it to be disabled. Perhaps you need to change your design approach

Comment: No I mean I didn't need to disable all the editText I want only to disable the editText that I didn't click.

Comment: I can enable it again by using the last one enable EditText. All I need is to correct go to my else condition in my given code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
myHolder.txt_Qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {

                if(isError){
                    Log.i("afterchange errorPos", String.valueOf(errorPos));
                    S_4th_SelectItem.lst_listOrder.getChildAt(errorPos).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 153, 204));
                    S_4th_SelectItem.btn_Update.setEnabled(false);

                    myHolder.txt_Qty.setEnabled(false);

                    ((Activity) context).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                }else {
                    S_4th_SelectItem.btn_Update.setEnabled(true);

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Waqas's answer will work, another solution which is quite costly is to loop through all the other list items and disable each EditText In them, not too elegant but will do the work.